# Manual exercise question numbering

Tags: numbering, counters, exercises

I am using [exercise](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/) package to list exercises/questions. 
I am defining exercise list like this:

```
\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise{Exercise title}

  \ExeText
  Some exercise introduction
  \Question{First question}
  \Question{Second question}
  \Question{Third question}
\end{ExerciseList}
```

In the output questions are numbered like this:

```
1. First question
```

However my desire is to have following output:

```
(a) First question
```

Actually it would be best if I could manually define list letter for question as I anticipate some gaps in numbering later. For example `\Question{e}{Some question}`.
From the package source I see that questions are translated to list items:

```
\def\@QuestionHeader{\item[{\makebox[0cm][r]{\begingroup\@getQuestionInfo%
\QuestionHeaderDifficulty\QuestionNB\endgroup}}]%
\begingroup\@getQuestionInfo\QuestionHeaderTitle\endgroup\ignorespaces}
```

However I am unsure on how to redefine the macro in order to accomplish my goal.. Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good on you to look in the source code.  Good on the package author to use good macro names that describe the intent.  I guessed from your posted snippet that `\QuestionNB` might be the macro that typeset the question number.  Searching the source file for that string found me:

```
% Presentation of Questions
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\arabic{Question}.\ }
```

Excellent!  We know `\QuestionNB` sets the arabic representation of the value the `Question` counter, with period and space.  So all you have to do is insert

```
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{(\alph{Question})\ }
```

into the preamble after `\usepackage{exercise}` and you'll get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{(\alph{Question})\ }
\renewcommand{\theQuestion}{(\alph{Question})}
\begin{document}
\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise{Exercise title}

  \ExeText
  Some exercise introduction
  \Question{First question}
  \Question{Second question}\label{q2}
  \Question{Third question (\textit{Hint}: use your answer to question~\ref{q2})}
\end{ExerciseList}
\end{document}
```

([View this in CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/share/77102825-e295-4667-b66f-6775afeb829e/manual-exercise-question-numbering/manual-exercise-question-numbering.tex?viewer=share))

[image: sample code output]

The command `\theQuestion` is for setting the counter value in `\ref`erences.  So the line renewing it will take care of the situation described by Peutsch in the comments.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that referring to a question still uses the internal counter, which is numerical. Eg  \Question Second question \label{q2}
  \Question{Third question. Hint: use your answer to question~\ref{q2}} would display "Hint: use your answer to question 2."

Comment: @Peutch You are right, of course.  I've updated the answer to take care of this.